# JDBC-HiveServer:'client_protocol is unset!'-Both 1.1.1 in CS

Tags: scala, exception, jdbc, apache-spark, hive

When I ask this question, I have already read many many article through google. Many answers show that is the mismatch version between client-side and server-side. So I decide to copy the jars from server-side to client-side directly, and the result is .... as you know, same exception:

```
org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{use:database=default})
```

It goes well when I connect to hiveserver2 through beeline :)
see my connection.

[image]

So, I think it will work when I use jdbc too. But, unfortunately, it throws that exception, below is my jars in my project.

- hive-jdbc-1.1.1.jar
- hive-jdbc-standalone.jar
- hive-metastore-1.1.1.jar
- hive-service-1.1.1.jar
  those hive jars are copied from server-side.

```
    def connect_hive(master:String){
        val conf = new SparkConf()
                        .setMaster(master)
                        .setAppName("Hive")
                        .set("spark.local.dir", "./tmp");
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf);
        val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
        val url = "jdbc:hive2://192.168.40.138:10000";
        val prop= new Properties();
        prop.setProperty("user", "hive");
        prop.setProperty("password", "hive");
        prop.setProperty("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
        val conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, prop);
        sc.stop();
      }
```

The configment of my server:

> - hadoop 2.7.3
> - spark 1.6.0
> - hive 1.1.1

Does anyone encounter the same situation when connecting hive through spark-JDBC?

Comment: How do we connect hive through spark not jdbc?

Answer (score 0):

Since beeline works, it is expected that your program also should execute correctly.

#### print current project class path

you can try some thing like this to understand your self.

```
import java.net.URL
import java.net.URLClassLoader

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

object App {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader
    val urls = cl.asInstanceOf[URLClassLoader].getURLs
    for (url <- urls) {
      println(url.getFile)
    }
  }
}
```

Also check  `hive.aux.jars.path=<file urls>` to understand what jars are present in the classpath.

Comment: alright, I will try this. Additionally, I am confused about how to connect hive through spark not jdbc, is there some methods to do this?

Comment: spark + hivecontext : hivecontext.sql("select * from abcd ") returns DataFrame

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. It seems like i forgot some configment?

Comment: Open Hiveserver2-0.0.0.0:10000; Open Spark-master & worker; when I use hiveContext, it throwed so many exception...

Comment: Thank you~ I tried this, but it fails, the hivecontext in the article are in spark-shell, not in client-side (such as eclipse in win10)

Comment: Sorry! I never executed spark on windows.

Comment: Never mind~ I means I install spark in my linux server, but my client side is windows. Thank you for your answers~

Comment: but were you able to solve original problem as suggested above?

Comment: I solved the problem by just using jdbc to connect hive. Ignoring the Spark....And it works :)